# Statistics - Proving -uniform random variables

Tags: statistics

Suppose $U_1$ and $U_2$ are independent uniform random variables on $[0,1]$.
Show that $$\frac{\log(U_1)}{\log(U_1)+\log(U_2)}$$ is also uniform random variable.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us begin by computing the following probability:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{\log U_1}{\log U_1 + \log U_2}\leq t\right] & = \mathbb{P}\left[\log U_1 \geq t\log U_1 + t\log U_2\right] \\
& = \mathbb{P}[(1-t)\log U_1 \geq t \log U_2] \\
& = \mathbb{P}\left[U_2 \leq U_1^{\frac{1-t}{t}}\right]\\
& = \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}\left[U_2 \leq U_1^{\frac{1-t}{t}}\big|U_1=a \right]\underbrace{p_{U_1}(a)}_{=1}da \\
& = \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}\left[U_2 \leq a^{\frac{1-t}{t}}\right]da \\
& = \int_0^1 a^{\frac{1-t}{t}}da \\
& = t.
\end{align*}
Hence, we are done.

Above, $p_{U_1}(\cdot)$ is the probability density function of the random variable $U_1$.